# ¿Cómo traducir "worldsheet" en relatividad?

Tags: traducción, ciencia

En relatividad cuando un objeto puntual se mueve en el tiempo decimos que traza una línea de universo, del inglés "worldline". Si el objeto es de 3 dimensiones, pues cubriría un tubo de universo, del inglés "world tube". Pero si el objeto es de dos dimensiones, el término en inglés sería "worldsheet", que no le encuentro una buena traducción al español. Las opciones serían "sábana de universo", "lámina de universo" o "cortina de universo", pero todas me parecen un poco... raras. ¿Hay algún término "oficial" para esto? ¿Cuál es el más usado? En los apuntes de mi curso de relatividad sí mencionan una "sábana de universo", pero lo ponen así, entre comillas, dando a entender que es un término mal encajado pero sin mejor traducción. ¿Es así?

Answer (score 5):

En Wikipedia en español, que a falta de otra indicación debemos suponer que toma el término de otras fuentes más o menos de autoridad, *worldsheet* se traduce como "[hoja de universo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoja_de_universo)". Esta es la traducción elegida, por ejemplo, en la versión en español de *The Universe in a Nutshell* de Stephen Hawking. El término también aparece bastante en las búsquedas de Google.

Comment: Tampoco hay que olvidar que el libro que citas lo tradujeron como "El universo en una cáscara de nuez", que en español no tiene ningún sentido :)

Comment: En ambos casos eligieron, a falta de otra cosa, la traducción más literal posible. *"In a nutshell"* es figurativo pero comprensible; cuando Shakespeare inventó la frase, no sé cómo la habrán recibido sus contemporáneos.